# Why do certain replied emails missing threading when replied back in Mutt?

Tags: linux, email, vim, imap, mutt

I use Mutt for emails.  I have threads enabled and I can see that most of the emails are threaded in Mutt. So that is all good. But sometimes I reply to an email and the answer(from other person) to my replied email wont be part of any threads. The thing is that when I reply in Mutt (which I use Vim to edit them), the subject parts keeps getting longer and longer with many "Re"s. That is the case with those emails with missing threads.

I have:

```
set strict_threads="yes"
set sort="threads"
set edit_headers=yes
```

I am wondering if this has anything to do with Mutt or the person I am communicating over email.

Could this one be the culprit?

```
set metoo=yes
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 methods for grouping messages into threads. The strict method is not by subject, but by analysing the references to previous messages in the message header (`in-reply-to` and `references` headers).

I use this method, which is controlled in mutt by setting the option `strict_threads`.

This works OK in almost every case, and allows the subject to be adjusted without risk of breaking the thread.

Be careful, knowing that you have `edit_headers` set, not to delete these references as you edit your message.

In the rare cases when someone replies without the correct reference headers, I manually attach it to the thread:

1. tag the child message(s)
2. go to the parent message
3. press `&` (`<link-threads>`)

The second method (which is the default, with `strict_threads` unset) groups messages by subject. This is probably your case, and therefore fails if the subject is modified.

The variable `sort_re` allows you to specify how picky mutt is about grouping by subject.

Here is online documentation for [`strict_threads`](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/manual.html#strict-threads) and [`sort_re`](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/manual.html#sort-re).

Comment: Great help. Thanks. I did not know that I could relink threads. That was immense help. No wonder Mutt is wonders. Also having multiple tagged emails does not work with & linking. One has to use tag prefixing ; for multiple tagged messages. In any case this is great. Do not forget to apply your changes also ;)

Comment: What I do most often is break threads (with `#`). People are used to replying to old messages for completely unrelated issues just for reusing the addressees. BTW, in mutt you can always use esc-E to create a message based on another one.